# Google Map with InfoBubbles

Tags: javascript, google-maps

On [this page](http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/festival/map?location=IRELAND&types=BIG_MUSIC), I show a Google map with [InfoBubble](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html)s that appear over the map markers. The InfoBubbles are open initially. If you close them, you can re-open them by clicking on the marker. I would like the InfoBubbles to be closed initially. The relevant function (simplified to remove irrelevant stuff) is:

```
addMarker = function(festivalData, hasPopup) {

    var map = this._map;

    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(festivalData.latitude, festivalData.longitude),
        map: map
    });

    if (hasPopup) {
        var infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
            map: map,
            content: "<a href='" + festivalData.url + "'>" + festivalData.name + "</a>",
            hideCloseButton: false,
        });

        infoBubble.open(map, this.marker);

        var infoBubbleHandler = function(bubble) {
            return function() {
                if (!bubble.isOpen()) {
                    bubble.open(map, this.marker);
                }
            }
        }(infoBubble);

        google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'click', infoBubbleHandler);
    }
}
```

I expected that by removing the line

```
infoBubble.open(map, this.marker);
```

this would achieve my goal, but this just removes the InfoBubbles completely so that they don't even appear when you click on a marker. How can I make the InfoBubbles appear closed initially, but they open when you click on a marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed all references to this.marker to a local variable, and changed the creation of that handler function, and it works the way I think you want it to

```
addMarker = function(festivalData, hasPopup) {

    var map = this._map;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(festivalData.latitude, festivalData.longitude),
        map: map
    });

    if (hasPopup) {
        var infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
            map: map,
            content: "<a href='" + festivalData.url + "'>" + festivalData.name + "</a>",
            hideCloseButton: false,
        });

        //infoBubble.open(map, this.marker);

        var infoBubbleHandler = function() {
            if (!infoBubble.isOpen()) {
                infoBubble.open(map, marker);
            }
        };

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', infoBubbleHandler);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy way to make a marker invisible at the beginning and pop it open at click

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(some_lat, some_lng);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: your_map,
        title: some_title,
        zIndex: some_z_index_int,
        clickable: true
    });

infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
      content: '<div>Some label</div>',
      shadowStyle: 1,
      padding: 0,
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(57,57,57)',
      borderRadius: 4,
      arrowSize: 10,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#2c2c2c',
      disableAutoPan: true,
      hideCloseButton: true,
      arrowPosition: 10,
      arrowStyle: 2
    });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {

            infoBubble.open(map, marker);
        }
})(marker, i));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange behavior, I would also expect it to work after removing *open* call.

From the top of my head - try to close the bubble immediately after opening it:

```
infoBubble.open(map, this.marker);
infoBubble.close();
```

Comment: I've already considered this. It's my last resort if I can't find a "proper" solution. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I agree that this is not a "proper" solution. Check if _open_ in infoBubbleHandler is even called. If it is, then there is nothing else you can do but debug the _open__ method of the InfoBubble I guess :/